# Define Input and Output Parameters for Cloud Function Using Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to execute server-side code when called by client via React app. I have many different functions, each of which takes different input parameters, and return a `data` object with various attributes.

I would like to create a hook called `useFirebaseFunctions.ts` using which I can make the request, and in doing so, see all the input parameters that function requires, and the expected output results.

Within my hook, I've written the following function:

```
async function generateReport({ organisationId, projectId }: {
    organisationId: string;
    projectId: string;
}): Promise<{
    data: {
        id: string;
        fileName: string;
        numOfRows: number;
        createdOn: number;
    };
}> {
    const request = httpsCallable(functions, 'adminFunctions-generateReport');
    return request({ organisationId, projectId });
}
```

For the `adminFunctions-generateReport` function, the parameters are:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| organisationId: string | id: string |
| projectId: string | fileName: string |
|  | numOfRows: number |
|  | createdOn: number |

**Issue**

However, TypeScript displays an error on the `return request({...)};` line:

> Type 'HttpsCallableResult' is not assignable to type '{ data:
> { id: string; fileName: string; numOfRows: number; createdOn: number;
> }; }'.   Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: string; fileName: string; numOfRows: number; createdOn: number; }':
> id, fileName, numOfRows, createdOn

How can I properly type the function to get expected behaviour without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I re-declared the function as:

```
async function generateReport({ ...params }: {
    organisationId: string;
    projectId: string;
}) {
    interface ResInterface {
        id: string;
        fileName: string;
        numOfRows: number;
        createdOn: number;
    };

    const response = httpsCallable<any, ResInterface>(functions, 'adminFunctions-generateReport');
    return (await response({ ...params })).data;
};
```